# External translations editor for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, localization

Is there anyway to install the Android Studio Translations editor without installing the whole of Android Studio?

This is my use case:
I am in the process of making an app, that uses resource strings wherever text is needed. I want to translate my app, but not having any language skills to do so myself, I am getting someone else to do so.
They are not a technical user so editing the XML directly is not an option, and I don't really want to make them install Android Studio, so are there any other options?

I would be surprised if this isn't a normal use case, so what do people normally do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In those cases, what developers usually do is converting the string XML files to CSV, so that a translator can easily use excel to translate what's needed.

When the work's done you just convert the CSV back to XML.

There's an [Android Studio plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7782-android-strings-xml-to-csv-converter) that can help you with that, or as an alternative, you can use this [python script](https://github.com/jpjodoin/android-strings-to-csv).